# How can I use MouseLeave / Enter as a boolean?

Tags: c#, mouseevent

I am fairly new to C# and I am trying to change the color of a menustrip item when the mouse 'leaves' the button after its selected. But I can't use the MouseLeave as a boolean as it is an event. It tells 'MouseLeave can only appear on the left hand side of +='. Any tips?

Here is what I tried to do:

```
    if (e.Item.MouseLeave)
            {
                using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80)))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.Graphics.ClipBounds);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is an *Event* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Windows is event driven and for entering and leaving there are event where you could set and clear a flag. However you write about a menu itemyou want to color and also about a button.. Please tell us more about these: Are they the same? What kind of menu is it? What is entered, what selected?

Comment: its a menu strip in a windows form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a global boolean:

```
private void frm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrl.MouseEnter += ctrl_MouseEnter;
    ctrl.MouseLeave += ctrl_MouseLeave;
}

private bool bMouseInside = false;

private void ctrl_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bMouseInside = true;
}

private void ctrl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bMouseInside = false;
}
```

To use in your code:

```
if (!bMouseInside)
{
    // using (Brush b etc..
}
```

Comment: what is the 'ctrl' supposed to be? Where do I define it?

Comment: @user1842140 The button in your question

Answer (score 0):

As MouseLeave is an event on a control, try something like this:

On creating the control, add a method to the event handler:

```
control.MouseLeave += control_MouseLeft;
```

Then define the action that you want to occur in your control_MouseLeft method.

```
void control_MouseLeft(objet sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(80, 80, 80)))
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.Graphics.ClipBounds);
    }  
}
```